# Existe comando para alterar um type criado pelo usuário no Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu criei um type no meu banco de dados Sql Server:

```
CREATE TYPE [dtNumero] FROM [numeric](18, 5) NOT NULL
```

Existe algum comando para que seu possa alterar esse type, por exemplo a precisão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível alterar diretamente a estrutura do `type` (algo parecido com `ALTER TYPE`).

O que é possível é criar um tipo temporário com uma nova definição, alterar todos as tabelas com esse campo no seu banco de dados e por fim renomear o novo tipo criado:

```
/* Adiciona um novo UUDT 'temporário' com a nova definição */ 
exec sp_addtype t_dtNumero_tmp, 'numeric(18,5)', NULL 

/* Cria um alter table para todas as  tabelas que usam o tipo que será alterado
 * Copie e cole o resultado gerado */ 
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE dbo.' + TABLE_NAME + 
       ' ALTER COLUMN ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' t_dtNumero_tmp' 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where DOMAIN_NAME = 't_dtNumero' 

/* Exclui o tipo antigo */ 
exec sp_droptype t_dtNumero

/* Renomeia o tipo temporario para o nome antigo */ 
exec sp_rename 't_dtNumero_tmp', 't_dtNumero', 'USERDATATYPE'
```

<sub><sub>Baseado na seguinte resposta do SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1383509/2099835</sub></sub>